# Zoom on webview not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I have class extends webview, when onTouchEvent is found zoom not working.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.cancelLongPress();
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
        e.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    super.cancelLongPress();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
Add that too

```
wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: Try my answer now. Add both